# Can you identify the source of these rendering mistakes with a wind/cloth physics setup?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, force-fields

[image]

The image on the left is rendered viewport, and on the right is the render. I have a cloth modifier applied to flowers and leaves, and a wind forcefield in the scene. The simulation runs correctly in my rendered viewport. I haven't baked anything and just hit render animation, first frame renders fine and when the physics begin 2nd frame I get these glitches. Any ideas? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to bake the cloth before render

Comment: thanks, i've tried that, i get the same result

Comment: ok, then pls provide blend file because you gave us nearly no information at all...

Comment: My guess is a modifier, eg subsurf who's render settings differ from the viewport settings.

Comment: Yes, either a modifier with different settings for viewport and render or a modifier disabled in viewport and enabled in render.

Comment: Thank you three so much. Frederik and Gordon you were right. The Subsurf was above Cloth in the modifier stack, I dragged it below the cloth and it works now. I was just downsizing the file to isolate the problem and share the blend. And you got it right, thanks to you both for your help.